# How to call process by name or tags in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing module. This module is works on Queue that is its pick random process and assign the entery from Queue.

I want to decide which process will work on which entry of Queue

Here is my requirements,

I will pass 2 parameters to queue

1. Initiator Process name
2. Action/method ( What process is going to do)

Its should pass queue Entry to given Process only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Process` objects take an optional name argument on initialization.  You can use that name as a key in a dictionary:

`child_procs = {'name1' : Process(target=myprocfunc, name='name1'), ...}`

As for IPC between the parent process and the children, you should be fine with just maintaining a separate `multiprocessing.Queue` for each child process.  You'll need a task distribution object/function to assign work.  This function would probably be responsible for popping the task from the main/central queue and then assigning it to the correct child process queue (based on the architecture I am gleaming from your question).